# Understanding weapon system in Neverwinter Nights

Tags: neverwinter-nights

I just got a free copy of the old game Neverwinter Nights Diamond Edition so I decided to give it a shot. For a person who's not played old RPGs, this was a head hurting experience, because i was unable to understand stuff. But I slowly learned bit by bit. Still one basic thing I'm unable to figure out is weapon system. I somehow found what is 1d4 and similar stuff. But what about attack speed? How do I know that? And second what is Base Critical Threat and does the damage type and size of the weapon affect attacking in anyway, because it all felt the same to me, or maybe I'm wrong. Nevertheless, if someone can explain this or even put up a link which would help me out, would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The basics that you need to understand are Dungeons & Dragons concepts, as that is what NWN is based off of.  Specifically, D&D 3rd Edition.

First off, combat happens in what is called "rounds".    In 3rd edition, each round represent six seconds of time, so ten rounds would be a minute.  At first, each class only gets one attack per round, and it's represented by their base attack bonus.  So every class has the same attack speed at level 1.  For instance, take a look at the [Monk](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/monk.htm):

```
Level   Base Attack Bonus
1st     +0 
2nd     +1 
3rd     +2 
4th     +3 
5th     +3 
6th     +4 
7th     +5 
8th     +6/+1
9th     +6/+1
10th    +7/+2
11th    +8/+3
12th    +9/+4
13th    +9/+4
14th    +10/+5
15th    +11/+6/+1
16th    +12/+7/+2
17th    +12/+7/+2
18th    +13/+8/+3
19th    +14/+9/+4
20th    +15/+10/+5
```

At 8th level, you see +6/+1.  That means they get two regular attacks, one at +6 to hit, the second at +1.  At 15th level, they get another one.

This can be altered by some attacks, and notably, dual wielding means you get an extra attack per round, with a to hit penalty for both attacks.  This penalty is reduced if the off-hand weapon is classified as a light weapon, or is balanced.  To prevent confusion, dual wielding doesn't give you an extra attack per regular attack; it's just one extra attack.  At 8th level, you would have three attacks, not four.

There are some other skills that give you an extra attack for that round, such as Flurry of Blows, but that *is* your entire attack for the round; you can't use it twice, once for each attack.

Base Critical Threat is based on the weapon you're using.  Normally, the way critical hits work is that you first roll a twenty sided dice to see if you hit or not.  If you roll a number within the Critical Threat Range, you have the potential for doing a critical hit.  You roll another to hit roll, and see if that attack would hit the monster.  If so, congratulations!  You've done a critical hit! Your damage dice are multiplied by the critical damage on the weapon.  One thing to note is that if your second roll wouldn't actually hit the monster, then it's not a critical hit, but you still hit the monster.  Roll normal damage dice.

Here are some examples:

A sword has a Base Critical Threat of 19-20/x2.  This means if you first roll a 19-20, you have the potential of critting.  Roll again.  If this roll with your to-hit bonuses would hit, you crit, and you roll your damage dice.  Some people roll the regular weapon damage and just double it, some people roll twice as many dice.  Either way works.

An axe has a Base Critical Threat of 20/x3.  For this to crit, you have to roll a 20, and then roll again to hit the monster, but if you do, the damage is *tripled*.

There's a bare bones intro to combat in D&D.  That should allow you to make some more sense out of the numbers you're seeing on weaponry.

Comment: I've never played NWN1, did it not include the later Two-Weapon fighting feats in D&D that let you make an extra off-hand attack per iterative?

Comment: One minor clarifying note: If you manage a critical threat (i.e. rolling that 19 or 20 with a sword), but don't *confirm* it (i.e. hit when you roll the second time), your attack still hits for normal damage. Increasing critical threat range (i.e. going from 20 to 19-20 to 18-20 and so on) is one of the best ways to increase damage for melee characters in NWN's particular implementation of D&D rules.

Comment: @Namfuak Indeed it does, and as Frank notes, there are a variety of other ways to add extra attacks beyond what BAB grants you. That's one of them.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Right before the examples: "One thing to note is that if your second roll wouldn't actually hit the monster, then it's not a critical hit, but you still hit the monster. Roll normal damage dice."

Comment: One thing to clarify here:  While the critical threat system seems complex it's really just a 5% chance of a critical hit for every number within the threat range.  It's just the system in the book involves less die rolling than simply rolling the percentage would--meaningless on the computer, important when you're playing pencil and paper.

Comment: @LorenPechtel That's not entirely true as written. If your critical threat is also a miss you will not roll for confirmation. So if you can only hit your foe on a 19/20 but have a threat range of 17-20, an 18 on your attack roll will only be a miss.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Good point, although if you're in that situation you ought to run!

Comment: @LorenPechtel There are a few enemies with insane AC but little offensive power.  I believe there are some magical suits of armor at the end of the first act of the vanilla campaign that fall into that category.  Very tedious to fight without non-physical options...

Comment: Well that's why my dual bastard sword wielding dwarf warrior was so good. Nice Breakdown.